# Sun X4100: "LSI Configuration Utility Text Strings Image memory error!"

Tags: raid, sun, bios, x86

We have a used X4100 (not M2). It has an option during the boot process that says

```
LSI Logic Corp. MPT SAS BIOS
MPTBIOS-6.04.07.00 (2005.11.03)
Copyright 2000-2005 LSI Logic Corp.


Press Ctrl+C to start LST Logic Configuration Utility...
```

I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Then the last line changes

```
Please wait, invoking LSI Logic Configuration Utility...
```

After a few seconds, I get two more lines

```
Configuration Utility Text Strings Image memory error!
Rebooting..
```

The expected behavior and what has worked on other X4100s is to come up with the BIOS-style tool to set up RAID.

I think the solution is to clear out its image memory. Like a factory reset. I have already done factory reset in BIOS, ILOM.

Does anybody know what the error is about, how to fix it, or how to factory reset LSI and MPT BIOS?

---

I have already upgraded the firmware to a newer version and it did not help. I am trying now to download the latest firmware package that includes LSI, but it is more than twice as large and Oracle seems to have inherited some of Sun's broken web systems. The download site does not work well, hangs and interrupts, etc. It is the Server 1.4 download from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html#X4100 which is a four pack of firmware upgrades, it is the latest one that contains MPT BIOS and LSI. I already have up to date BIOS and ILOM.

I will also look around in the regular BIOS and look for a reset for the LSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success!

For those who find this. You need to update the LSI and MPT BIOS to not be so far behind the ILOM and regular BIOS. Whoever updated the ILOM/BIOS either did not read or did not heed the "readme"s

Get updates here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html#X4100